# Counting rows from multiple tables in a single query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

I've been trying to make a query more efficient by bringing together counts from multiple tables. I have a schema similar to this:

```
create table "impressions" (
    id serial primary key,
    ip inet,
    ad_id integer references ad(id),
    user uuid references user(id),
    created_at timestamp default now()
)

create table "purchases" (
    id serial primary key,
    ip inet,
    ad_id integer references ad(id),
    user uuid references user(id),
    // ... few other columns
    created_at timestamp default now()
)

create table "clicks" (
    id serial primary key,
    ip inet,
    ad_id integer references ad(id),
    user uuid references user(id),
    created_at timestamp default now()
)
```

And I've been trying to get a `count(*)` of `impressions`, `purchases` and `clicks` grouped by `user`. And later by `ad_id`. I'm currently doing 3 separate queries to the database and aggregating in application code, but wondered if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: please add also data and your three queries.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Does using count on full outer joins not solve your issue?

Comment: Get a count of activity on every table, grouping by the common column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all three counts into a single query to make it a single round-trip to the DB server, which saves some overhead, and reduces I/O.

OTOH, joining rows adds some cost (depending on the number of distinct users). But if you are going to do that anyway, it's typically *much* cheaper in Postgres than in the client. Postgres is optimized for the task and can work with original data types.

```sql
SELECT u.id, i.impressions_count, p.purchases_count, c.clicks_count
FROM   "user" u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS impressions_count
   FROM   impressions
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) i USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS purchases_count
   FROM   purchases
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) p USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS clicks_count
   FROM   clicks
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id);
```

By basing the query on the `"user"` table, users without any entries in the three subsidiary tables are listed, too. If you don't want those, combine the subqueries with `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` instead:

```sql
SELECT id, i.impressions_count, p.purchases_count, c.clicks_count
FROM  (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS impressions_count
   FROM   impressions
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) i
FULL   JOIN (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS purchases_count
   FROM   purchases
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) p USING (id)
FULL   JOIN (
   SELECT "user" AS id, count(*) AS clicks_count
   FROM   clicks
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id)
```

Either query reports `null` where no rows are found. You may want to convert that to `0` with `COALESCE(i.impressions_count, 0) AS impressions_count` etc.

If table rows are wide (and your tables are vacuum'ed enough) you can gain performance from an index on `("user")` on each subsidiary table. You probably have that anyway.

Aside: "user" is a fully [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL. I'd rather not use it as identifier, even if that's allowed with double-quotes. Too error-prone.

Comment: I had no idea you could place a select inside a JOIN operation like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've misunderstood, but is this what you want?

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    _user, COUNT(_user) AS cnt
  FROM impressions
  GROUP BY _user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    _user, COUNT(_user)
  FROM purchases  
  GROUP BY _user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    _user, COUNT(_user)
  FROM clicks
  GROUP BY _user
)
SELECT _user, SUM(cnt) 
FROM cte
GROUP BY _user;
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/yGX0Pv0k

Comment: What is the difference between a CTE with UNION and outer joins?